Looking for a 80s-90s cartoon movie where some small animal gets into hands of humans
I'm looking for an old cartoon from the 80s or 90s. 
Some orange-furred (I can't remember its species) animal gets lost (somehow?) from a forest, gets into a human populated area. 
Mid-story, it escapes a child's room, later it swims through some sewer (but can't pass a barrier inside the water), tries to scare someone with grinding its teeth, also people try to hunt it for some reason.  
At the end, it safely returns to the forest.

By your description, I think it is Enchanted Journey (1984).

A domestically raised chipmunk, Glikko, befriends a carrier pigeon named Pippo (pee-poh), who tells Glikko of an enormous forest where chipmunks roam free. Enthralled by the story, Glikko leaves his home in the city and sister in search of the Vast North Forest. Along the way he meets up with another chipmunk named Nono, whom Glikko reluctantly allows to accompany him. On their journey they are faced with dangers such as predators and the Winter climate.

Gikko, the orange chipmunk tries to reach the forest, but he has to go through a city first.
